# How to combine Material UI dashboard with Appbar+Sidelist with react-fullscreen-image

Tags: reactjs, navbar, fullscreen, appbar

I use material UI like in this template (https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/templates/dashboard/ to get appbar and a sidelist. Next to the sidelist I have several pages. One of them is a picture gallery with the click-on-fullscreen capabilities from that source https://github.com/timc1/react-fullscreen-image including Left/Right/Close Button.

When using the gallery in my application, the left button is hidden behind the sidelist and the x button for closing the image is hidden behind the appbar.

I could imagine three solutions, but don't know how to realize one of them yet.

1. Hide appbar+sidelist in click event
2. Force image to display over everything that is visible elsewhere
3. Force all buttons in page area next to sidelist and beneath the appbar (not going fullscreen anymore)

Trying "sticky" instead of position="fixed" on the appbar didn't work. The appbar filled the whole website.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I consulted good old ChatGPT this morning, and it guided me in the correct direction.

The ImageGroup of the react-fullscreen-image is wrapped in a div container. Its css parameters are only a padding distance of zero in the basic settings. I added position:relative and z-index:100000. So the group of pictures is still nicely aligned next to the sidebar and below the appbar. But the picture in fullscreen is now above the app- and sidebar.